# C Segmentation fault even when using EOF

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, eof

I'm loading a file into memory and I am doing so with the following statement:

```
        if ((ch = fread(&temp[i],1,1,loadDict)) == EOF)
            break;
```

But I receive a segmentation fault. Upon inspection using gdb I verified that the fault is happening at this line (the if statement, before the break). Why does it not see that it will fault (the whole point of using EOF)?

I thought it might be that I'm using the EOF in an if statement rather than within a while() statement. Is it possible to use EOF in an if statement?

Update: More Code

```
bool load(const char* dictionary)
{
FILE* loadDict = fopen(dictionary, "r");

char* new = malloc(sizeof(char)); // for storing the "new-line" character
*new = 0x0A;

// defines a node, which containes one word and points to the next word
typedef struct node
{
char* word;
struct node* next;
}
node;


    node* head = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node* temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    head->next=temp;

    // copies a word from the dictionary file into a node

    int* numStore = malloc(sizeof(int)); //count for number of words in dictionary
    int num = 0;
    int ch = 0; // to hold for EOF
    int flag = 0; // for breaking out of while loop
    while(true)
    {
    node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->next=newNode;
    temp->word=malloc(46);

        int i = -1;

        do
        {
        i++;
        if (!feof(loadDict) || !ferror(loadDict))
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        fread(&temp[i],1,1,loadDict);

        if  (memcmp (new, &temp[i], 1) == 0)
            num += 1;
        }
        while(memcmp (new, &temp[i], 1) != 0);

    temp=newNode;

    if (flag == 1)
        break;
    }

   numStore = &num;

return true;
}
```

Comment: ``fread`` does not return ``EOF``. Use ``ferror`` or ``feof`` to check. what's more, it's return type is ``size_t`` instead of ``char``(I think ``ch`` is type of ``char``) http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

Comment: Your problem is `&temp[i]`.

Comment: I don't think it's with &temp[i] (?)
Because when I change the size of the loadDict file the fault happens sooner or later, whereas the timing shouldn't change if it was an issue with the size of temp.

Comment: As @gongzhitaao says, try reading the documentation for the API you're using. It's a lot quicker and more considerate than posting a question.

Comment: I don't mean to be inconsiderate as I am new to programming and made an effort to find an answer elsewhere. But I do appreciate the feedback. I'll look into feof and ferror. Thanks!

Comment: is temp[i] a integer or char array ?? if integer , then size(second param), must be 4

Comment: @user2272798, it can be &temp[i]. you may or may not get a crash while accessing this mem. address, as it is depending on your environment.

Comment: You could provide a more complete, at least minimum runnable code so that we could see where the problem actually is. This code snippet does not tell much.

Comment: @BarathBushman temp is a variable I allocated using malloc. I am traversing the memory space using the var[] notation. I made it sufficiently large so I don't think that is where I am having issues, but I'm not positive. Let me post more code...

Comment: Please build a minimal, **compilable** testcase.

Comment: Always test the result of the actual I/O function (`fopen()` and `fread()` here).  Only use `feof()` or `ferror()` after one of the main functions has reported a problem.  You can't process the 'result' that `fread()` returned if `fread()` returned an error or EOF indication, but that's what your code does.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure I understand. How can I test the result of fread()? I was just told that fread does not return EOF in the first comment.

Comment: Do away with that disgusting `new` variable. Replace code like `if (memcmp (new, &temp[i], 1) == 0)` with code like `if (temp[i] == '\n')`. Don't use magic values like `13` and `46`. Which book are you reading?

Comment: The [`fread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) function returns 0 on error or EOF.  It returns a count of the number of items read, so you might also get a short read if there are fewer bytes to be read than you ask it to read.  So, you need: `size_t nbytes = fread(&temp[i], 1, 1, loadDict);` and you need to check that you get the result `1`.  In general, you get the number of records, but here your records are bytes.  It is also a travesty to use `fread()` to read one byte at a time; slow — but it will actually work.

Comment: The statement `int* numStore = malloc(sizeof(int));` is a bit pointless.  Why not just: `int numStore;`?  Less space; less danger of memory leakage.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue lol. I wish I had a good book :) That line came entirely out of trial and error. I've been trying to learn pointers and implemented it that way, but your line is much more elegant.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My reasoning there is that this is a function I am implementing and I want that number to be accessible outside the scope of the function, so I gave it a memory address.

Comment: @jstaker7 You can't learn C by trial and error because of undefined behaviour. Code that invokes undefined behaviour might appear to work on your system, while failing in subtle or devastating ways on other systems. Given that you seem to understand *some* aspects of C, I suggest testing yourself with K&R's "The C Programming Language", second edition. Read the chapters, do the exercises... Consider `char c = '\n'; char *pointer_to_c = &c;` or `char s[1] = "\n"; char *pointer_to_first_byte_of_s = s;`.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the code, or are you looking for lines in the file, each line minus its newline to be stored in a node?  If so, you're using the wrong function; `fgets()` gets lines.  Also, the type `node` must be defined outside the function if it is to be used outside the function...well, you can get into debates about compatible types, but that's doing things the hard way.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm loading words from a text file with each word (ending in a new line) stored in a node. Then linking the words together in a linked list to make them searchable. Hmm... that is a good point about the nodes.

Comment: Are you doing anything else with temp before?

Comment: You aren't returning the linked list from the function or the number of entries; indeed, you only ever return `true`.  How is the outside world to get at your dictionary?

Comment: @mohit Before the pasted segment of code? No, it is declared and first used in the above code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Very true. I don't know, to be honest. I have to figure that out. I can see how returning the address of the first node would be ideal, but I have to implement it in such a way that it returns true. I'm working on Harvard's CS50 homeworks even though I'm not in the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiles...I've now run it too.  The error handling on failure to allocate is reprehensible; it should at minimum give an error message and should probably free all the allocated nodes and return 0 (NULL) from the function (and close the file).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    char        *word;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

Node *dict_load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *loadDict = fopen(dictionary, "r");

    if (loadDict == 0)
        return 0;

    Node *head = 0;
    char line[4096];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), loadDict) != 0)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(line);           // Includes the newline
        Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
        if (node == 0)
            exit(1);    // Reprehensible
        node->word = malloc(len);
        if (node->word == 0)
            exit(1);    // Reprehensible
        memmove(node->word, line, len - 1);  // Don't copy the newline
        node->word[len-1] = '\0';            // Null terminate the string - tweaked!
        node->next = head;
        head = node;
    }

    fclose(loadDict);
    return head;
}
```

If you've got to return a `bool` from the function, then you probably need:

```
static bool dict_load(const char *dictionary, Node **head)
```

If the argument list is fixed at just the file name, then you're forced to use a global variable, which is nasty on the part of the people setting the exercise.  It's 'doable' but 'ugly as sin'.

The code above does work (note the tweaked line); adding functions `dict_free()` and `dict_print()` to release a dictionary and print a dictionary plus proper error handling in `dict_load()` and a simple `main()` allows me to test it on its own source code, and it works (printing the source backwards).  It gets a clean bill of health from [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I'll work through your answer and I'm sure I'll learn from it.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again. In the last few minutes I've been researching how I could go about accessing my head node. I am indeed stuck to the one file name, but I do have access to a headerfile. So my first thought is that I can declare the node struct in the headerfile. I'll give it a whirl... good old trial and error.

Comment: The header would contain the type definition, the function declarations (you're going to need the `dict_free()` and probably the `dict_print()` functions as well as `dict_load()`), and — since your hands are tied — a global variable (`extern struct node *head;` in the header, and `struct node *head = 0;` in the source file).

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef struct node
{
char* word;
struct node* next;
}
```

The structure that you defined can crash, at least the implementations I have seen has. The char* inside the node has no fixed value. So when you do :

```
node* head = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

The malloc() will allocate a memory of (taking 1 byte for char pointer, and an int size pointer for node, defaulting to 4 bytes on a 32-bit machine) 5 bytes. What happens when you read more than 5 bytes?

Also, you are needlessly complicating this:

```
int* numStore = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

If you want to store the number of words in the dictonary, straight away use an `int numstore`, less headache :)

```
    while(true)
    {
        node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->next=newNode;
        temp->word=malloc(46);
        ...
    }
```

Now, this here is an interesting concept. If you want to read till the end of file, you have got two options:
1) use `feof()`
2) at the end of the loop, try this:

```
   while(true)
   {
       ....
       if(fgetc(loadDict)==EOF) break; else fseek(loadDict,-1,SEEK_CUR);
   }
```

Also, this line: `temp->word=malloc(46);`
Why are you manually allocating 46 bytes?

Armin is correct, &temp[i], while i does get allocated to 0, the do{...}while(); is completely unnecessary.

Also from man fread : http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fread/
You are reading what looks to me like 1 character.

In my opinion, try something like this:

set a max value for a word length (like 50, way more for practical purposes)
read into it with fscanf
get its length with fscanf
allocate the memory

Also, you do not need to allocate memory to *head; It can be kept as an iterator symbol
I almost forgot, how are you going to use the returned list, if you are returning bool, and the *head is lost, thus creating a memory leak, since you can't deallocate the rest? And unless you are using c99, c doesn't support bool

```
/*Global declaration*/

typedef struct node
{
    char* word;
    struct node* next;
}node;

node *head, *tmp;
/* for the bool if you really want it*/
typedef enum { false, true } bool;

node* load(const char* dictionary)
{
    FILE* loadDict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    char word[50];
    int num = 0;       
    int len;
    node *old;  
    while(true)
    {
    /*node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->next=newNode;
    temp->word=malloc(46);*/
        fscanf(loadDict,"%s ",word);
        len = strlen(word);
        tmp = malloc(len + sizeof(node));
        strcpy(tmp->word,word);
        tmp->next = NULL;
        if(head==NULL)
        {
            head = tmp;
            old = head;
        }
        else
            old->next = tmp;
        old = tmp; 
        num++;
        if(fgetc(loadDict)==EOF) break; else fseek(loadDict,-1,SEEK_CUR);    
    }
    printf("number of counted words::\t%d\n",num);
    fclose(loadDict);
    return head;
}
```

Also, please remember that i have only accounted for the act that words are separated by one space per, so please load the file t=like that, or change the algo :) Also, be sure to free the memory after using the program !

```
void freeDict()
{
    node *i;
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        i = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(i);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks! One question though. I see what you mean about node* head = malloc(sizeof(node)). Does this not work to do this: temp->word=malloc(46)? For the head I am not storing anything except a pointer to the first word-containing node.

Comment: Yes you are, but you are _manually_ assigning the value. Bad idea in my books :) Also, the concept of head is not to contain anything except to be used as a _finder_ for the list. Head only stores the address of the first node in the list. Think of them like boxes. Each box has a rope linking them to the next box, but they are in a dark room. So,if you don't know where the first box is, say goodbye to the rest!

Comment: Fixed a typo, added fclose(). Tell me if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You're use of temp[i] raises suspicion that you might be accessing outside memory.
To quote from K&R:

```
If pa points to a particular element of an array, then by definition pa+1 points 
to the next element, pa+i points i elements after pa, and pa-i points i elements
before. 


These remarks are true regardless of the type or size of the variables in
the array a. The meaning of ``adding 1 to a pointer,'' and by extension,
all pointer arithmetic, is that pa+1 points to the next object, and pa+i
points to the i-th object beyond pa.
```

Comment: he has initialized `i` to `-1` so it should be fine.

Comment: since `temp` is `node *`, which is presently pointing to allocated memory. If `memcmp (new, &temp[i], 1) != 0` returns true, you would be reading to memory outside the allocated region.

Comment: I have many iterations of my loop proceed without error, suggesting that it can return true without causing a segmentation fault. Also, &temp[i] is first accessed by fread(&temp[i],1,1,loadDict); so wouldn't that return an error before the memcpy statement?

Comment: no what mohit is saying is right. suppose you have char `a` and `b` in the file. 1st time you read a and do `memcmp`, it doesnt match with`*new` now you have to make `temp = temp->next`and malloc again.this should be done within the `do while`. but i think instead of `&temp[i]` you meant `temp->word[i]` to store the data?